# NSOperationQueue Pause & Resume?

Tags: multithreading, macos, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, manualresetevent

I implemented Thread pooling using `NSOperationQueue`. In which i set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to `25`. i.e. concurrently 25 threads are running at a time.

I am uploading chunks to a server by using this `NSOperationQueue`. So chunks are allocated to  the first 25 threads. After the `NSOperationQueue` is full, I want to pause the chunking reading part, then whenever threads from the queue complete, resume the chunking part to allocate new threads to `NSOperationQueue` to replace the thread which complete.

My Code:

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount=5;

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self                                                                         selector:@selector(upload:)                                                                            object:f_objChunkDetails->FileStream];

NSUInteger oprCnt=operationQueue.operationCount;

if(oprCnt >= 5) {
    // wait till queue has a free slot
} else {
    [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}
```

So how to pause and resume is used in `NSOperationQueue`? How to implement `ManualResetEvent` in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

Don't wait or pause. Instead, move your job creation (and check) into a new method. That method should loop to create jobs up to the available limit and then return. Each job that is created should have a `completionBlock` added which calls the job creation method.

In this way you are event triggered instead of blocking.

Generally, the `completionBlock` should change to the main thread before calling the job creation method.

Comment: Currently i am achieving uploading part using NSOperationQueue  so uploading data to server requires time.. And data which are going to upload is coming from ReadData class which is execute fastly.. So i want to pause the ReadData till NSOperationQueue has space if queue contains space ReadData start working and next data is assign to NSOperationQueue.. In C# it achieve using ManualResetEvent class. What is feasible solution for objective-c? How we can achieve ManualResetEvent for multiple Thread?

Comment: If you dislike my solution above you could use `NSConditionLock`.

Comment: I like your solution but is thr any other way to do this.. I want feasible solution. NSConditionLock or NSLock shared the resources... I want to pause and resume my each thread separately.. As per my knowledge NSConditionLock will not achieve this.. If you think so that NSConditionLock is better option then can u please provide me sample code... Like in c# we use ManualResetEvent Class which uses set,Reset, waitOne method for pause and resume... What is   suitable option for objective-c(MAC). Please give your valuable suggestion...

Comment: My answer is a feasible non-blocking solution. If you want a blocking solution then `NSConditionLock` can be used as a counting semaphore. As can `dispatch_semaphore_t`.